# Is there an easy way to tell which layout was inflated to create a convertview in an Adapter?

Tags: android

I have a custom abstract adapter that extends BaseAdapter.  Is there a magical way to detect  (from a child class of this adapter) what layout resource was used to inflate the convertView that is passed to getView(..)?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  // TODO what resource was inflated for this convertView if its not null?
}
```

I could probably do it by setting an ID on the top level element of each of the potential views (the top level element may be the same Layout for all of the potential views) - but am hoping there is a "magic" trick for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this. For one, the convertView may have been created dynamically in code rather than inflated.

It sounds like you're trying to populate your view differently depending on the type of the item that you are asked to display. If that's the case then Android already has a mechanism for this. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) out. If you implement getItemViewType() then you're guaranteed that you get the right convertView in your getView() call.